# Drive to US, fly from there to Hawaii without passport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, paperwork

If one does not have a passport in Canada, can they drive to the USA, then fly to Hawaii without a passport? Would I be able to use my Canadian driver's license as valid photo ID?

Comment: Is the Canadian license an enhanced drivers license?

Comment: Yes, so I can cross the border by car. I'm thinking that since once I'm in the states, it would just be a regular domestic flight, and that the ID requirements would be less than requiring a passport.

Comment: Good question. Every time I think of a finger-waggling you shouldn't...I end up talking myself out of it. Can't wait for answers from those more knowledgeable than I.

Comment: mmm, it looks like despite the huge distance from the mainland US to Hawaii there isn't really anything else along the way. So even if things go wrong you are not likely to end up at a foreign airport.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, if you have an **enhanced** driver's license, this should work.

You have already noted in comments that your enhanced driver's license allows you to cross into the US by land.  And according to [this page](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/acceptable-ids), a Canadian driver's license is acceptable by TSA as ID for boarding flights at US airports.  Flights between the continental US and Hawaii are ordinary domestic flights, so no further documentation is required beyond a TSA-acceptable ID.

Answer (score 9):

You said in comments that you have an enhanced driver's license, so you can enter the US. While a foreign driver's license normally isn't enough to fly in the US, a Canadian license *is* on the [TSA acceptable ID list](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/acceptable-ids%20), so your license is all you'll need to drive across the border and take the flight.